# Prevent clicks on actionbar menu

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, click

I want to create some animation on my activity and for this reason I need to be able to show the actionbar menu icon (the three dots one) but in same time to block programmatically any click event on it.

I need something alike:

```
setClicksOnActionbarMenuEnable(false); // any click on my actionbar menu icon will be disabled

doMyAnimation();

setClicksOnActionbarMenuEnable(true); // actionbar menu icon will accept again clicks.
```

I have searched everywhere and couldn't find any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solution:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
final View child = toolbar.getChildAt(2);
if (child instanceof ActionMenuView)
{
    final ActionMenuView actionMenuView = ((ActionMenuView) child);
    actionMenuView.getChildAt(actionMenuView.getChildCount() - 1).setEnabled(false);
}
```

If don't have a navigation drawer replace with:

```
 final View child = toolbar.getChildAt(1);
```